# SELECT all rows that are 2 WEEKS old FROM NOW

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a query that selects all rows of data from a table in my database. I am using PHP and MySQL. Instead of grabbing all of the rows in my table, I would like to only grab rows that are between now and two weeks old. How can I do this? I know I would need to add a WHERE clause

My Code So far:

```
$notifications_query= "SELECT * FROM notifications ORDER BY recieved DESC";
```

The column containing the date that will be used is named 'viewed' and it is in 'datetime' format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$notifications_query= "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE yourdatecolumn BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW() ORDER BY recieved DESC";
```

Comment: Are you sure the two dates don't need to go the other way around? I think BETWEEN expects the smaller argument first, although I admit I'm suddenly doubting myself.

Comment: @James you probably are right, from documentation `This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max)`

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE viewed BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND now()
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a where clause that contains the datediff() function explained here

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$notifications_query= "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE viewed BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE ";
```

received definition must be date in order for the query to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$twoweeksago = time()- (3600*24*14);
$notifications_query= "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE viewed > {$twoweeksago}  ORDER BY recieved DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've had an assortment of answers, because there are a whole bunch of ways to do this -- and some subtleties.

The simplest, if your received value is NEVER in the future, is to do something like...

```
WHERE received > DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY )
```

or

```
WHERE DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), received ) < 14
```

If your received value can be in the future as well, and you just want the slice from 14 days ago to today, that's not much trickier:

```
WHERE received BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY ) AND CURDATE()
```

or again,

```
WHERE DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), received ) BETWEEN 0 AND 14
```

One thing you should think about in addition to this: is received a date field, or a datetime field? CURDATE() is always midnight of today when compared to a datetime, so these BETWEEN queries may actually omit datetimes that fall during the course of today -- as they will fall after (e.g.) 2013-06-19 00:00:00, the datetime value of CURDATE. If that's an issue for you, use NOW() instead.